# How to convert CGRect to CGPoint iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cgrect, cgpoint

Here i want to convert `UIImageView`'s `maxY` `CGRect` value to `CGPoint`, but when i tried to convert `CGRect` value to `CGPoint` i got an error.

- Code

```
let cgPoint = imgPin.convert(imgPin.frame.minY, to: self.view)
```

- Error

> Expression type '@lvalue CGRect' is ambiguous without more context

Comment: Convert your `Double` value to `CGFloat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass a `CGPoint` instead of `CGFloat` as below,

```
// set x, y as per your requirements.
let point = CGPoint(x: imgPin.frame.minX, y: imgPin.frame.minY)
let cgPoint = imgPin.convert(point, to: self.view)
```

**OR**

You can pass the `CGRect` as it is and get the point as `origin`,

```
let cgPoint = v.convert(imgPin.frame, to: self.view).origin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension:

```
extension CGRect {
    var topLeadingPoint: CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: minX, y: minY) }
    var topTrailingPoint: CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: maxX, y: minY) }
    var bottomLeadingPoint: CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: minX, y: maxY) }
    var bottomTrailingPoint: CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: maxX, y: maxY) }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
let cgPoint = imgPin.frame.bottomTrailingPoint
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this to convert point from `imgPin` to `self.view`

```
let cgPoint = imgPin.convert(imgPin.frame.origin, to: self.view)
```